# Action to Navigation bar back button

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show an alert with Confirmation when user clicks on back button. This is how I'm trying to add action.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.save(sender:)))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

This is working fine but I want the default back button image in it and not the custom title. How to do that ?

I tried following code as well :

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.action = #selector(ViewController.save(sender:))
```

...but the action is not performed, too.

Comment: I think you just can set the properly image of back arrow, here is the [assets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30110190/4929876) download it and add it to the custom back button.

Comment: self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true; If it's true? That means you cannot get the standard back button and their icon too.

Comment: @Mannopson Yes I had set it to true.

Comment: @Nitesh I have the same problem, perhaps it's a bug. I have used the Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.0

Comment: @Nitesh have you already tried my suggested solution by using `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods?

Answer (score 5):

This might help. This wont override back action, but you can do additional task.

Objective c

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if(self.isMovingFromParentViewController)
    {
        //On click of back or swipe back
    }
    if(self.isBeingDismissed)
    {
        //Dismissed
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",self.isBeingDismissed);
    NSLog(@"%d",self.isMovingFromParentViewController);
}
```

Swift

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated);
    if self.isMovingFromParentViewController
    {
        //On click of back or swipe back
    }
    if self.isBeingDismissed
    {
        //Dismissed
    }
}
```

Comment: but alert is not presented if I do it by this way.

Comment: Alert wont be shown on this view controller because it is about to be disappear. try showing on previous view controller which will be shown.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution!

I tested it on iOS 11 and  iOS 13 and it works fine :)

```
protocol CustomNavigationViewControllerDelegate {
    func shouldPop() -> Bool
}

class CustomNavigationViewController: UINavigationController, UINavigationBarDelegate {
    var backDelegate: CustomNavigationViewControllerDelegate?

    func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        return backDelegate?.shouldPop() ?? true
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CustomNavigationViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        (self.navigationController as? CustomNavigationViewController)?.backDelegate = self
    }

    func shouldPop() -> Bool {
        if (needToShowAlert) {
            showExitAlert()
            return false

        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well for me. However, don't you need to clear backDelegate when SecondViewController disappears?

Answer (score 1):

You need add custom back button to Navigation bar, and add action to it

```
      let backButton = UIBarButtonItem (image: UIImage(named: "ico-nav-prev")!, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(GoToBack))
      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
      self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

     func GoToBack(){

        self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you try to achive, but isn't it a possible solution to do, what you want, whenever `vieWillDisappear:` got called? This is maybe a matching entrypoint without fiddeling around with the back-bar-button suggested in the other answers.

**Better**
Another option would be to implement the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, set your controller as `delegate` and then implement your alert in `navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)`.

Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate) for reference.

Comment: I need to display an alert when user press the back button. Alert will have button with "Yes" and "No". I tried it on viewWillDisappear but my alert was not presented on it

Comment: Added another option that should fit in your situation.

Comment: It is gets called when view is presented and every time on push, etc. I want it only on back.

Comment: @Nitesh you have to check whether the `viewController`that will be shown is the one you want to show the alert before and then you're done!

Answer (score 0):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21869626/3393877) should do the job.

You basically create your button with the default style and register a selector.

And you might try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31198470/3393877) for a **backButton** instead of leftButton:

**Objective-C**

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[desVC.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backBtn];
```

**Swift**

```
let backBtn = UIBarButtonItem()
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBtn
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this line of code inside of your `ParentViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method not the `ChildViewController`

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Remove the following line of code from your `ChildViewController`

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

And you'll be Ok! If you need to create an action for this transition, I mean whenever the user taps the back button from your `ChildViewController`. Simply call this method inside of your `ChildViewController`

```
 override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.didMove(toParentViewController: parent)

    if parent == nil {

    } else {

    }
}
```

**Edited:**

*ChildViewController*

```
 override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.didMove(toParentViewController: parent)

    if parent == nil {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init("Post"), object: nil)
    } else {

    }

}
```

*ParentViewController*

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handler(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "Post"), object: nil)

}

func handler(notification: Notification) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This is works but with a problem like so:

**Warning: Attempt to present  on  while a presentation is in progress!**

Therefore I don't recommended. Good luck

Comment: But by this Alert view is not presented.

Comment: But this alert will be a little problem

Comment: My main purpose of doing this is to display an alert when back is pressed.

Comment: I'll show you. But you'll be warned from the system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135199/discussion-between-mannopson-and-nitesh).